# How to effectively fix this error in trying to use Matlab in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, virtualenv, version

When I used `python setup.py install`, I always got the following error message even when I tried to uninstall my Python and install Python version 3.7:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    raise EnvironmentError('MATLAB Engine for Python supports Python version'
OSError: MATLAB Engine for Python supports Python version 2.7, 3.6, and 3.7, but your version of Python is 3.8"
```

So How to effectively fix this error and get the most updated version of Python?

Thanks a lot for any helpful answers!

Comment: Use `python --version` in the same environment to check what you have.

Comment: Okay, it shows Python 3.8.3. How to install Python 3.7 by command? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you have created a virtualenv for this installation you better create a new one but this time use the full path to the pyenv script or python executable of version 3.7.

Comment: I think it would be helpul to know which platform/distribution you are currently using ? For starter : Windows, Linux ?